# What is a "terrace park"?

Tags: meaning

In an autobiographical book, the narrator, an American, tells about a period he spent in Kiev:

> The front door of my building opened onto the bustling but cozy street of Zhitomirskaya, and it was an easy walk to Saint Sophia Square. There was also a nice terrace park where the young and hip of Kiev would gather in the late afternoon to throw Frisbees, play bongo drums, and drink beer in the glow of the sunset.

What is a "terrace park" (I mean it as a common noun, not as the name of a specific place or town)? Is it actually a park extending on terraces?

Comment: Can you give more context, please?

Comment: Yes, sorry. In an autobiographical book the narrator tells about a period he spent in Kiev. "The front door of my building opened onto the bustling but cozy street of Zhitomirskaya, and it was an easy walk to Saint Sophia Square. There was also a nice terrace park where the young and hip of Kiev would gather in the late afternoon to throw Frisbees, play bongo drums, and drink beer in the glow of the sunset."
So it is definitely a park but would it be built on terraces, or is it an idiom for something else?

Comment: It sounds to me like it could be a transliteration from Russian or Ukrainian; I don't know what it means.

Comment: @DaG: I copied your comment into the question text, where it should be. I don't know if the option to edit your own question text requires a certain minimum rep score, but that would seem unlikely to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, well done. I have further edited to add a detail (the writer being an American).

Comment: @DaG: I shall be mortally wounded if you don't accept my answer now! I still can't believe I got so carried away digging into it! (prima facie evidence that I have far too much time on my hands! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for your great research work! You seem to have pinpointed the exact meaning in this case. I wonder whether this is a local use of some part of the States, since other English native speakers do not immediately identify it. (And could you please un-downvote Theta30? He just tried doing some research in the same direction as you did, and there is nothing wrong in itself in understanding a word by finding the item the word is referred to, even if the word itself is not mentioned in the sources.)

Comment: @DaG: It's not meaningfully even a "local use". Bear in mind that I only found two relevant instances of *"a terrace park"* in Google Books - one was for the "small garden/park associated with residents of a terrace", the other for "larger terraced (landscaped) public park area". They're just two different adjectival usages of the word "terrace" - neither expression is "established". But it probably *is* true to say most Americans wouldn't think of *terraces* as being rows of houses, since such buildings aren't common in the US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This particular pair of words isn't at all common ([this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hBbhTTbgDu0C&q=%22a%20terrace%20park%22&dq=%22a%20terrace%20park%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=d2FKT5izIeGg0QX2xoCUDg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAA) is one of very few relevant references to *"a terrace park"* I could find in Google Books). From OED:

> **terrace** 5: A row of houses on a level above the general surface, or on the face of a rising ground; loosely, a row of houses of uniform style, on a site slightly, if at all, raised above the level of the roadway.

So in OP's context, it could be a small urban park/garden area, associated with one or more terraces around it, possibly for the exclusive use of the people who live in those terraces. I believe that in London, for example, some such areas have locking gates, to which only the residents have keys. Note that originally, such *terraces* were quite grand structures housing the well-to-do, but latterly the term has come to be applied to small cramped houses built together for economy (when UK estate agents advertise a [mid terrace house](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mid-terrace%20house&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=VLFKT6iFMYKk8gPrn-y4Dg&ved=0CGIQsAQ&biw=1359&bih=885) it's usually a rather humble dwelling).

---

Alternatively, noting OP edit that the author is American, it could be that he's simply using the adjective *terrace* to indicate that the park is on a slope, with one or more flat "platform" sections naturally occurring or cut into the landscape (OED sense 2: *Geol., a horizontal shelf or bench on the side of a hill, or sloping ground.*)

This is [Stern's guide to the greatest resorts of the world](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%20terrace%20park%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22in%20a%20terrace%20park%22&psj=1&oq=%22in%20a%20terrace%20park%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=61207l62646l1l62885l4l4l0l0l0l0l53l178l4l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4c3a76122614ebc0&biw=1359&bih=885) describing the [Beau-Rivage Palace](http://www.booking.com/hotel/ch/beaurivagepalace.en.html?aid=311076;label=slhp_hotel-65243-ch-oIBgnQBA8i7vXPY9yzJ*JwS11099098980;sid=d5eb73d00533893d1f371cb7cd585331;dcid=1;gclid=CO7kz9XVvK4CFZARfAod1jQSLQ) hotel:

> This elegant, traditional European grand hotel, which originally opened its doors in 1861, sits in a **terrace park** overlooking Lake Geneva in the heart of the Swiss resort area of Lausanne-Ouchy.

[image]

...where as the picture suggests, the area around the hotel probably *is* landscaped into flat terraces.

EDIT: Okay, curiosity piqued, I couldn't resist chasing this one down. I Googled [relief map kiev Zhitomirskaya](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&psj=1&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2064l14453l0l14839l25l25l0l0l0l1l245l1887l22.2.1l25l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1359&bih=885&q=relief%20map%20kiev&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x40d4cf4ee15a4505:0x764931d2170146fe,Kiev,%20Kyiv%20city,%20Ukraine&gl=uk&t=p&ei=8c9KT-2dCYm_8wOL1Ym8AQ&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=image&resnum=1&ved=0CEIQ8gEwAA), and from that map discovered there's a park near that street called [solom'yans'kyi lisoparc](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=solom%27yans%27kyi+lisoparc&psj=1&oq=solom%27yans%27kyi+lisoparc&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1353l21358l0l22003l23l23l0l0l0l0l181l1567l21.2l23l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=bf56d27dba7e0d1b&biw=1359&bih=885). Googling that soon found me [this picture](http://static.panoramio.com/photos/original/21783676.jpg)...

[image]

...so clearly it's the second meaning here. Quite a large park in a hilly area with various terraced sections, not a small "residents only" garden/park such as you might find in central London.

Comment: Given that the author is an American, and that this is a singularly British meaning of "terrace" (British *terraces* are called *row houses* in the U.S.; the word *terrace* is used only for porches, patios, and multilevel landscaping or farming), I think this interpretation is quite unlikely.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Possibly. But I note that according to [Steven Holl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Holl) (apparently a famous American architect that I'd never heard of before), [The continuous row of identical houses forming a repetitive wall of facades along the street is a unifying house type that is rare in North American cities.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oAWkvAW4p_cC&pg=PA50&dq=%22row+of+indentical+houses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1ppKT4bCHIq_8wO8i92hDg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22row%20of%20indentical%20houses%22&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a park located on a terrace or slope, perhaps with nice view of the river Dnieper. You can see such a slope at the beginning of this Youtube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rKt7OFfApA)
Other [source](http://www.kievcity.com.ua/culture-and-art/observational-points) talks about such a hill:

> The vision is open from several levels – in addition to the highest, there is a points below the slope. The advantages of these observation points include the location in the heart of the city; it’s a park, closeness to the St. Michael Monastery and the Sofia square, and also the existing cable railway.

Comment: -1 because your **source** link is clearly written by someone with only limited command of English, and neither that nor your youtube link include the word "terrace" anyway.